# Four Pillars of Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

I have come across to a statement in many Functional Analysis books saying that

"Hahn Banach theorem, Uniform Boundedness Principle, Open mapping theorem and Closed graph theorem are the four pillars of Functional Analysis"

I don't exactly know why they are so important, maybe these are used in many parts of Functional Analysis further.
can anyone help me, please?
thanks and regards in advance.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: That they are important will be obvious if you continue to read the book.

Comment: I just edited it

Comment: These theorems are used again and again in functional analysis.

Comment: ya, I know that but is there anything more precise than that @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Just like ordinary linear algebra has its own toolkit of three-four theorems, linear algebra in Banach spaces has these four pivotal results that capture essential properties of of how continuity of linear functionals works.

Comment: The question is to give a big picture overview of how these theorems are useful in functional analysis. I'm interested to hear the answers as well.

Comment: @littleO  I also agree with that

Comment: Ok, here's a ig picture overview of how the closed graph theorem is useful.  The theorem says that if $T$ has a closed graph then $T$ is bounded. The big picture of how this is useful is that when you can show $T$ has a closed graph you can conclude that $T$ is bounded. (Is that a useful comment? No. Is it a silly comment? Yes. But it _is_ the big picture. If you want to actually understand why these theorems are important, _read the book_.)

Comment: Yeah you are right @DavidC.Ullrich

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on my study of the subject I think I have enough information that I can answer my own question.

Hahn-Banach Theorem: It is so much important because it provides us with the linear functionals to work on various spaces as Functional Analysis is all about the study of functionals.

Open Mapping Theorem: It provides us with the open sets in the topology of the range of the mapping.

Uniform Boundedness Principle: An application of Baire Category theorem. It is further used many times as the uniformity is an important property.

Closed Graph Theorem: Closeness of the graph of a map is enough to prove its boundedness or continuity. This fact is further used many times.

Answer (score 0):

This article might be of help.

[https://www.imsc.res.in/~kesh/trinity.pdf](https://www.imsc.res.in/%7Ekesh/trinity.pdf)